# How to read month/day/year in an American way?

Tags: american-english

British people would say "I have a meeting on the 8th day of Sep in 2019." I guess American would say "I have a meeting on Sep 8, 2019." But how to read "on Sep 8, 2019" in a natural way?

Comment: That sounds too stilted or epic-speak for a contemporary British speaker. Normally a Brittish or Irish person  would say (written out in full) 'I have a meeting on the eighth of September' or 'I have a meeting on September the eighth.'

Comment: British *and* American speakers use both ***the eighth of September*** and ***September the eighth*** interchangeably. Only slow-witted speakers would be likely to be influenced by whether they were "translating" from a written instance of British DDMMYY or American MMDDYY conventions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe it's just my local area, but, while they are both acceptable and technically interchangeable, ***the eighth of September*** is rarely used in everyday conversation. For that matter ***September THE eighth*** is also rare, compared to the shortened ***September eighth***. I cannot speak for British conventions, but where I'm from "I have a meeting on the eighth of September" *might* sound a *little* out of place, but nobody would really care. (Funny, if said with a British accent in the US, I doubt anyone would find it strange at all!)

Comment: Thank you all so much for these helpful comments.

Comment: @WillRoss1: I don't see a big difference between [AmE usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+8th+of+May%2CMay+the+8th&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%208th%20of%20May%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMay%20the%208th%3B%2Cc0) and [BrE usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+8th+of+May%2CMay+the+8th&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%208th%20of%20May%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMay%20the%208th%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%208th%20of%20May%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMay%20the%208th%3B%2Cc0) here...

Comment: ...for both corpuses, ***the 8th of May*** is way more common than ***May the 8th***

Comment: @FumbleFingers Again, ***May THE 8th*** IS rare, in both cases. [***May 8th***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+8th+of+May%2CMay+the+8th%2CMay+8th&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%208th%20of%20May%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMay%20the%208th%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMay%208th%3B%2Cc0) (as written in the OP) is far for common in American English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers (That said, your point still stands as [***British English***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+8th+of+May%2CMay+the+8th%2CMay+8th&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%208th%20of%20May%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMay%20the%208th%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMay%208th%3B%2Cc0) follows a similar trend, indicating that there is, in fact, no significant difference in usage between AmE and BrE :)

Comment: As a BrE, I have never read or heard "on the 8th day of Sep in 2019". Although technically correct, in reality it would never be used. This question also changes depending if you're talking about written English or Spoken English. "on the 8th September" would be read (out-loud) as "on the 8th of September" but is very rarely written as such.

Comment: @WillRoss1: Yeah - I'd certainly agree that Americans are more likely to drop the article before "day number". Not sure whether that extends to dropping the ***ordinal*** form (giving just ***May 8*** rather than ***May the 8th***) in general conversational contexts, or whether that ultra-clipped "jargonny" form is largely restricted to office / military contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, us Americans like to shorten stuff. ***May 8th*** is almost *always* what is used in conversation. (Written communication often uses the ***05/08*** form instead, but never ***08/05***. ***May 8*** and ***8 May*** are occasionally found in written form as well.) ***May the 8th*** is almost nonexistent. *Really* formal = ***the 8th of May***, everything else = ***May 8th***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"September 8th, 2019" is by far the most common in everyday speech, and feels perfectly natural to Americans. "The 8th of September, 2019" is more formal and less common, typically only used for invitations and the like.

Additionally, in most cases the year is omitted and it is assumed that you mean this year, so 09/08/2019 would be spoken as "September 8th".